# Project linker installation error in VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xamarin, mobile-devices

I get the following error message when I'm trying to install Project linker extension for VS2012 both web and desktop: " VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products. " What should I do? I want to develop a mobile application,and I want it to be cross-platform,wrote in c#. Do I have any other options? I want to use Xamarin studio,any experiences with it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Portable Class Libraries](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/) instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I'm still confused..I should use PCL in regular Visual Studio or in Xamarin Studio?

Comment: Either.  They both support them.